# disabled dates not updating on view when we add through button click

Tags: javascript, datetime, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have used vue-hotel-date-picker its working fine. the issue is when using disabled dates props its disabled the dates first time when initializing and update on calendar.but when i update disabled dates array on any button click event it updates the disabled dates array but not reflect or render in view component. I have debug it through vuejs chrome extension.

Here is an image when debugging
[image]

plugin [link](https://github.com/krystalcampioni/vue-hotel-datepicker)

Here is my **HTML** Code

```
<div class="box">
    <h3>Check in only on saturday and minimum stay of 10 days</h3>
    <DatePicker
      DatePickerID="01"
      :disabledDates = "disabledDates"
      :enableCheckout="true"
      :minNights="10"
      :useDummyInputs="false"
       placeholder="StartDate ► EndDate"
      />
  </div>
  <button @click="onChangeDisableDates()" > Change Disable Dates </button>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
import DatePicker from 'components/HotelDatePicker.vue';

export default {
    components: {
        DatePicker
    },

    data () {
      return {
         disabledDates : ['2017-08-18']
      }
    },
    methods : {
      onChangeDisableDates () {
         this.disabledDates.push("2017-08-19");
      }
    }
};

</script>
```

I don't know how to figure out and solve this problem , it might be issue in this plugin,any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What does your implementation look like? How can you expect any help if you don't show what you've done?

Comment: @Phil i have edited my post you can check Thanks

Comment: Why are you binding `placeholder` to a static string? Why not simply `placeholder="Rent-in ► Rent-out"`? Never seen the `dependencies` array for a component, what's that?

Comment: When i used simple for placeholder it doesnt reflect thats why i tried to binding, dependencies is my own services you can neglect this

Comment: Isn't the problem that it's not showing your placeholder in either case?

Comment: yes its not showing and also disabled dates not working as well @Phil

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152045/discussion-between-wasiq-muhammad-and-phil).

Comment: @phil i have updated my question and hoping it will clear to understand it would  be great if you check this

Comment: Looking at the `vue-hotel-datepicker` code, I'd say they need to add a watcher for `disabledDates` (among others) and pass the changes in to the `HotelDatePicker` instance and somehow update it. I see you've raised an issue on their github page so I think at this time, that's all you can do

Comment: @phil do you have any date range picker reference for vue that has option to disabled dates and  allowed ranges.it would be great if you share with me

Comment: Sorry, no I don't

Answer (score 2):

Write in computed: { } it will be updated then whenever there's a change.

```
import DatePicker from 'components/HotelDatePicker.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    DatePicker
  },
  data() {
    newDisabledDates: null
  }
  computed: {
    disabledDates() {
      // write your disable date change logic or fetch from any other data var
      if (this.newDisabledDates === null) {
        //default logic
        return {
          disabledDates: ['2017-08-18']
        }
      } else {
        // this.newDisabledDates would have been updated here if button clicked
        return {
          disabledDates: this.newDisabledDates
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onChangeDisableDates() {
      this.newDisabledDates.push("2017-08-19");
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
disabledDates(date) {
   var gDate = date.getDate(); 
   var gMonth = date.getMonth(); 
   var gYear = date.getYear();
   for(var i=0;i<(this.disabled.length);i++) { 
      var myarr = this.disabled[i].split("-");
        if(gDate == parseInt(myarr[2]) && gMonth == parseInt(myarr[1]) && gYear == parseInt(myarr[0])) { 
          return true;
        }
        else {
          return false;
        }
   }
}
```